# Multiple live bindings to a dom in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Assuming to a dom element i have more than 2 `live` bindings (or `delegate` for that matter). (one or more could be from jquery plugins i use), which one gets preference.

```
$(selector).live('click', function(e) {
  alert(1);
});

$(selector).live('click', function(e) {
  alert(2);
  e.stopPropagation();
  alert(3);
});
```

And then someone clicks the `selector`, all 3 alerts are shown.

Can someone explain?

PS: The underlying question is when there are live bindings at other places (read files), do they get overwritten, or do all get executed ?

Comment: [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is deprecated as of v1.7 and removed in v1.9 so better use [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) or [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: yup, i know. my curiosity was for `live`, as most plugins use it. @RobM's answer reminded me that I knew of this, just couldn't remember.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you unbind previous bindings, it will just add a new event listener and they will all get executed (unless something halts execution).

Answer (score 0):

They all get executed sequentially. <strike>You can stop subsequently called event handlers from happening by calling  event.stopPropagation().</strike>(Apparently not!) Strangely enough, if you call `$(selector).off('click')` it'll remove every single event handler attached to `.live('click')`. `.live` has actually been deprecated, and it's not recommended you use `.on`.

[Source](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Comment: stopPropagation doesn't stop events bound by live. http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/ the additional notes section.

Comment: @Arindam I didn't know that. Thanks for teaching me something!